# Why does styling TDs in jquery make the markup insane?

Tags: jquery, css, html-table, styling

I'm trying to add a simple border to all the table cells in a table.

It's important that my markup remains simple for some other functionality I have in place to work.

Let's say I style tds like this:

```
$('td').css('border', '1px solid #000');
```

this ends up as my result:

> `<td style=​"border-top-width:​ 1px;​
>   border-right-width:​ 1px;​
>   border-bottom-width:​ 1px;​
>   border-left-width:​ 1px;​
>   border-top-style:​ solid;​
>   border-right-style:​ solid;​
>   border-bottom-style:​ solid;​
>   border-left-style:​ solid;​
>   border-top-color:​ rgb(0, 0, 0)​;​
>   border-right-color:​ rgb(0, 0, 0)​;​
>   border-bottom-color:​ rgb(0, 0, 0)​;​
>   border-left-color:​ rgb(0, 0, 0)​;​
>   ">​…​/td>`

Classes also wouldn't be appropriate for what I'm trying to do.  Why are my cells being formatted in this ridiculous way?

Comment: this is happening in chrome specifically

Comment: Why wouldn't a class be appropriate?

Comment: this screams for CSS classes? why is that not appropriate? If you need to be able to switch them on the fly then I have an easy CSS solution, much cleaner

Comment: classes arent appropriate because the styling will be editable by the user

Comment: If you want it on all cells why not set the border attribute of the table?

Comment: @ionfish when you say "this is happening in chrome specifically" do you mean it *doesn't* do this in other browsers?  If that's true, you should add that to the question, and also specify what it *does* do in other browsers.  I would have guessed it would be the same in all browsers, as I can't see any reason for the difference.

Comment: Regardless of whether the *use-case* sounds like a good case for classes, the question isn't about that at all.  It's about why jQuery is doing something that seems stupid.

Comment: i'm doing more testing.. this isn't limited to tds.  for example, applying the same styling to divs or tables results in the same thing.

Comment: this is the way to get around it in case anybody is wondering..  $('td').attr('style', 'border: 1px solid #000;');

Comment: I'm curious: why you need the markup to be "simple"?

Comment: @ionfish, if you're seeing jQuery behave differently in Chrome (or any WebKit browser) than it does in other engines... isn't that a clue that the behavior is in the browser, rather than in jQuery? jQuery does ultimately rely on the browser's DOM implementation under the hood.

Comment: Why is the post-rendered interpreted markup of the DOM an issue? Your original markup is still the same, so this shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @ionfish:  **Why on Earth are you trying to make the markup in your DOM match your actual markup?**  I always thought of viewing the DOM as simply a troubleshooting tool.  Since it's just the particular browser's _interpretation_ of the markup, I do not expect it to match mine.

Answer (score 13):

This is how browsers handle shorthand CSS properties; some browsers may implement the human-readable representation differently from the internal representation, but in reality,

```
border: 1px solid #000
```

is shorthand for

```
border-top-width: 1px;
border-right-width: 1px;
border-bottom-width: 1px;
border-left-width: 1px;
border-top-style: solid;
border-right-style: solid;
border-bottom-style: solid;
border-left-style: solid;
border-top-color: #000;
border-right-color: #000;
border-bottom-color: #000;
border-left-color: #000;
```

with a number of possible representations of `#000`.

I tested in both Chrome and Safari (both WebKit browsers), and setting that property directly in the DOM (`element.style.border = '1px solid #000'`) had exactly that result. This is the behavior of *WebKit*, **not jQuery**.

Furthermore, this is a great example to underscore the fact that the DOM is different from markup, and ought to be treated differently. Even in a `designMode`/`contentEditable` scenario (which is the only *really* reasonable use of direct styling instead of CSS classes), just snatching the `innerHTML` representation of an element is a whole host of potential risks. You'll see other manifestations of this in older versions of IE, whose "markup" representations of the DOM are completely insane. It's not uncommon to see stuff like:

```
<div class="foo">...</div>
```

become:

```
<DIV CLASS="foo" _JQUERY12903579="qwertyuiop" HASLAYOUT=TRUE etc etc etc>...</DIV>
```

And just as DOM and markup are not the same thing, it's important to realize that an `attribute` and a `property` are not the same thing. Ultimately, the `jQuery.css` method is implemented by assigning values to properties of `element.style` (eg `collection.css({ border: '1px solid #000' })` is roughly equivalent to `collection.each(function() { this.style.border = '1px solid #000' })`; while `collection.attr('style', 'border: 1px solid #000')` is equivalent to `collection.each(function() { this.setAttribute('style', 'border: 1px solid #000'); })`. By setting the attribute rather than properties, what you're doing is effectively like retroactively editing the HTML markup. This can lead to unpredictable results if you also have properties set that conflict.

Also note that by using `attr('style', ...)`, you are probably overriding *all* of the elements' inline styles.

Comment: I don't think I need to post a separate answer since this is very good insight, however, you might want to mention that this is the difference between the `style=""` *HTML attribute* and the `.style.[cssattribute]` *property*.

Comment: Excellent explanation.  I always thought of viewing the DOM as simply a troubleshooting tool... I do not ever expect it to match my mark-up since it's just the particular browser's _interpretation_ of the markup.

Comment: In my defense, my answer is not incorrect, it is misleading :) At least knock me properly.

Comment: @Levi - unfortunately that's not true.  At first I thought you right, but @eyelidlessness is correct - setting properties of the `style` property results in this - jQuery or not. What you said was "jQuery applies the `.css('border', '1px solid #000')` directive in that manner.").

Comment: @Renesis: You are the one who is incorrect: note my wording BEFORE the portion you quoted: "The simple answer is . . . "  JQuery does not have to apply it do the way it does, as noted in this post.  It *could* keep it simple in the markup, but it chose not to as to not have possibly conflicting values.  I also feel it is important to note that I myself have upvoted this post.  Anyone who goes through the effort to explain this deserves such.

Comment: @Levi you are misunderstanding this answer then.  It's built into the DOM.  `jQuery.css()` sets the style *property*, not *attribute*, so no, it could not "keep it simple in the markup".

Comment: Yes, it could.  It could set the attribute, but as noted in this post, that could cause conflicts, possibly erasing other code, etc.

Comment: @Levi Suggesting that jQuery "could" do something that wouldn't even fulfill the spec of the function in question is not a reasonable "could" at all.

Comment: @LeviMorrison let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1023/discussion-between-renesis-and-levi-morrison)